# How to change the text color of font in legend?

Tags: python, colors, fonts, matplotlib, legend

Is there a way to change the font color of the legend in a matplotlib plot?

Specially in occasions where the background of the plot is dark, the default black text in the legend is hard or impossible to read.

Comment: You can also pass in what ever font properties you want through the kwarg `prop` http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend

Answer (score 48, accepted):

call `Legend.get_texts()` will get a list of Text object in the legend object:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.plot(randn(100), label="randn")
l = legend()
for text in l.get_texts():
    text.set_color("red")
```

Comment: mind sharing where the `legend` variable came from? :)

Answer (score 42):

As of matplotlib version 3.3.0, you can now directly use the keyword argument `labelcolor` in [`matplotlib.pyplot.legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend).

---

Example using the same color as the corresponding artist by setting `labelcolor='linecolor'`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 0, '-', label='spam')
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 1, ':', label='ham')
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 2, 'o', label='eggs')
plt.legend(labelcolor='linecolor')
```

[image: matplotlib legend text color: 'linecolor']

---

Example changing all text to white by setting `labelcolor='w'`, e.g. for dark backgrounds:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 0, '-', label='spam')
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 1, ':', label='ham')
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 2, 'o', label='eggs')
plt.legend(facecolor='k', labelcolor='w')
```

[image: matplotlib legend text color: all text white for dark backgrounds]

Answer (score 20):

Because `plt.setp` broadcasts over iterables, you can also modify the text color in one line:

```
# Show some cool graphs
legend = plt.legend()
plt.setp(legend.get_texts(), color='w')
```

The last line will apply the colour to all elements in the collection of texts.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do it with setp():

```
import pylab as plt

leg = plt.legend(framealpha = 0, loc = 'best')
for text in leg.get_texts():
    plt.setp(text, color = 'w')
```

this method also allows you to set the fontsize and any number of other font properties in one line (listed here: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html)

full example:

```
import pylab as plt

x = range(100)
y1 = range(100,200)
y2 = range(50,150)

fig = plt.figure(facecolor = 'k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg = 'k')
ax.tick_params(color='w', labelcolor='w')
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('w')
ax.plot(x, y1, c = 'w', label = 'y1')
ax.plot(x, y2, c = 'g', label = 'y2')

leg = plt.legend(framealpha = 0, loc = 'best')
for text in leg.get_texts():
    plt.setp(text, color = 'w')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Anyone looking to change the color of the TITLE of the legend; seems to only be available through the side door:

```
leg._legend_title_box._text.set_color('#FFFFFF')
```