# Python matplotlib scatter label color to white

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do i change the color of the label to white for for following code.  default prints in black.

when i try adding color='w' or color = 'white', it throws error saying color is not defined on plt scatter.

```
for a in [100, 300, 500]:
    plt.scatter([], [], c='lawngreen', alpha=0.8, s=a, label=str(a) + ' km$^2$')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(scatterpoints=1, frameon=False,labelspacing=1, loc='lower left')
```

Comment: works  fine for me on matplotlib 2.2.2

Comment: Its not working on Python 3.7

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-colour-of-font-in-legend)

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-89564537a321> in <module>
     25 plt.clim(3, 7)
     26 for a in [100, 300, 500]:
---> 27     plt.scatter([], [], c='lawngreen', alpha=0.8, s=a, label= 'w'(str(a)) + ' km$^2$')
     28     plt.setp(label, color = 'w')
     29 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the text colour of font in legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-colour-of-font-in-legend)

Comment: no....it throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment didn't seem to be clear enough, I'm copying the answer here.

Just use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-colour-of-font-in-legend). The code below also changes the background color so the white legend text is visible:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager
import numpy as np

for a in [100, 300, 500]:
    plt.scatter([], [], c='lawngreen', alpha=0.8, s=a, label=str(a) + ' km²')
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_facecolor('skyblue')
leg = plt.legend(scatterpoints=1, frameon=False,labelspacing=1, loc='lower left')
plt.setp(leg.get_texts(), color='white')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that `plt.setp(leg.get_texts(), color='white')` is just a shortcut to

```py
for text in leg.get_texts():
    text.set_color('white')
```