# matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend does not recognize labelcolor as argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm having some trouble trying to set the color of legend entries. I want to select
the same color as the line they are referring to. Here i post a runable script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [1,2],[1,2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y,label='test',color='r')
ax.legend(labelcolor='r')

plt.show()
```

And that's the error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    ax.legend(labelcolor='r')
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 406, in legend
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labelcolor'
```

However I saw in the [legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) that labelcolor should work as argument.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: check your matplotlib version.  This is a new feature in 3.3.0. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63273370/6361531)

Comment: Your script works for me with the latest Matplotlib. What version do you get for matplotlib according to this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#obtaining-matplotlib-version

Comment: Yes, I have matplotlib 3.1.1. I'm now trying to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade matplotlib to [version 3.3.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/whats_new.html#text-color-for-legend-labels)

Then try it again.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [1,2],[1,2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y,label='test',color='r')
ax.legend(title='Guide', labelcolor='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm trying to update it (I have the conda environment) but It seems I'm not able to. I've tried to use
conda update conda
conda update --all
conda install matplotlib=3.3.0

or even the commands suggested here https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib

Comment: You can try to do it using pip.... `pip install -U matplotlib`

Comment: @F.Addari You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy!