# How can I edit the text colour of my legend in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am currently trying to set the text colour of my legend to "white" but can not get it to work.
My current code:

```py
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='white', lw=1, label='Connection to Early Émigré'),
                   Line2D([], [], marker='o',linestyle='None', color='white', label='Early Émigré (by 1935)',
                   markerfacecolor='white', markersize=5),Line2D([], [],  marker='o',linestyle='None', color='black', label='Not Emigrated by 1935', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=5)]

ax = map_df.plot(color='dimgrey', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.075)
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements,, loc='lower right',prop={'size': 6})
```

Comment: please add a complete example so we can try to run it and help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the text colour of font in legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-colour-of-font-in-legend)

Comment: ```legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='white', lw=1, label='x'),
Line2D([], [], marker='o', linestyle='None', color='white', label='y',
markerfacecolor='white', markersize=5),
Line2D([], [], marker='o', linestyle='None', color='black', label='z',
                              markerfacecolor='black', markersize=5)]
    ax = map_df.plot(color='dimgrey', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.075)
    ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='lower right', prop={'size': 6}, facecolor="white")
    ax.set_axis_off()geo_df2.plot(ax=ax, color='white', linewidth=0.35, zorder=1)```

Answer (score 1):

In the ax.legend function, you can pass a keyword argument (kwarg) for both facecolor (background of the legend) and edgecolor (legend border). ([Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) here)

In this case, replace the last line with the following:

```py
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements,, loc='lower right',prop={'size': 6}, facecolor="white")
```

If you need to change only the text color, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-font-in-legend) to a similar question.