# Font and colour for Python matplotlib legend- superscript

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, legend, italics

Can someone help me make the R2 writing look like the rest? Especially not italics. This is my code below:

While I'm here can anyone tell me how to either

- get that R2=0.97 line in red writing to indicate that's what the red line is on the graph
  or
- insert a red line/red dash within the legend on that line?

I've seen other ways of doing it online but the way I've formatted my legend doesn't allow for it.

```
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Cambria"
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y_test, y_predicted ,s=10,color='darkslateblue',linewidths=1)
ax.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], 'k-', lw=2,)
ax.set_xlabel('Actual (%)',fontsize='large')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted (%)',fontsize='large')
y_test, y_predicted = y_test.reshape(-1,1), y_predicted.reshape(-1,1)
ax.plot(y_test, LinearRegression().fit(y_test, y_predicted).predict(y_test), color="red", lw=2)
ax.set_title('H2O REF')
handles = [mpl_patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="white", ec="white",
                                 lw=0, alpha=0)] * 4
labels = []
labels.append("$R^2$ = {0:.2g}".format(Rsquared))
labels.append("RMSE = {0:.2g}".format(rmse))
labels.append("MAE = {0:.2g}".format(mae))
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='best', fontsize='x-large',
          fancybox=True, framealpha=0.7,
          handlelength=0, handletextpad=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Instead of using latex format (`"$R^2$"`), you could use a unicode superscript 2: `"R²"`. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first solution, a possible way to achieve it is by only typesetting `^2` in the math environment and than setting the first label text to `red` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-font-in-legend), see code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpl_patches

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = x + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=50)

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Cambria"
Rsquared = 0.9
rmse = 0.8
mae = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.plot(x, x, c='r')

handles = [mpl_patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="white", ec="white",
                                 lw=0, alpha=0)] * 4

labels = []
labels.append("R$^2$ = {0:.2g}".format(Rsquared))
labels.append("RMSE = {0:.2g}".format(rmse))
labels.append("MAE = {0:.2g}".format(mae))
leg = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='best', fontsize='x-large',
          fancybox=True, framealpha=0.7,
          handlelength=0, handletextpad=0)

texts = leg.get_texts()
texts[0].set_color("red")
```

Alternatively, you can create legend entries including the red line with [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D).
The corresponding code down below overrides handles[0].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpl_patches
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = x + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=50)


plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Cambria"
Rsquared = 0.9
rmse = 0.8
mae = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.plot(x, x, c='r')

handles = [mpl_patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="white", ec="white",
                                 lw=0, alpha=0)] * 4

lines = []
handles[0] = Line2D([0], [0], color='red')
labels = []
labels.append("R$^2$ = {0:.2g}".format(Rsquared))
labels.append("RMSE = {0:.2g}".format(rmse))
labels.append("MAE = {0:.2g}".format(mae))
leg = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='best', fontsize='x-large',
          fancybox=True, framealpha=0.7)
```

Comment: thank you so much the second one works better i think. I have another silly question. Is there a way to let the RMSE and MAE go directly below the line since they dont corrospond to a coloured line. Basically shifting the lower two lines in the legend to the left?

Comment: Would adding the argument `markerfirst=False` to the `ax.legend` be a suitable solution?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. It does have an effect by moving the red line to the other side, but everything else is still aligned so now theres a gap on the right of RMSE and MAE