# Change title color of legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

how can one change the color of the title text in a matplotlib legend? For the rest of the text it is easy, but I cannot find the way to modify the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it:

```
legend = plt.legend(...legend details...)

plt.setp(legend.get_title(), color='white')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you no longer have access to a (previously created) legend from another namespace, you can also use `get_legend()`:

```
axes = pyplot.gca()  # Get current axes
axes.get_legend().get_title().set_color('red')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `labelcolor` to do this. Refer below borrowed example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-font-in-legend).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 0, 'b-', label='spam')
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 1, ':', label='ham')
plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.rand(10) * 2, 'o', label='eggs')
legend = plt.legend(title="Legends", labelcolor='linecolor')
plt.setp(legend.get_title(), color='green')
plt.show()
```

[image: OutputImage]

Comment: This does not work for the title, I tried it. But thanks

Comment: I should work. I am not sure may be i did not understood your question well. It clearly changed the `legend title color`. Is there anything specific you want, i can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now that you modified your first answer, it worked. In the first answer there was no title in the legend :)

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if that served the purpose ?

Comment: Well, the updated answer uses the code I had already posted in my answer...