# Match legend text color with symbol in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I made a scatter plot with 3 different colors and I want to match the color of the symbol and the text in the legend.

A nice [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18476999/3276471) exist for the case of line plots:

```
leg = ax.legend()

# change the font colors to match the line colors:
for line,text in zip(leg.get_lines(), leg.get_texts()):
    text.set_color(line.get_color())
```

However, scatter plot colors cannot be accessed by `get_lines()`.For the case of 3 colors I think I can manually set the text colors one-by-one using eg. `text.set_color('r')`. But I was curious if it can be done automatically as lines. Thanks!

Comment: How about `get_children` or `get_patches`? Could you provide a minimum working example? You may want to look into the legend methods for other ideas: https://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/legend_api.html

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Thanks for the suggestions! I tried `leg.get_patches()` before and nothing returns. I just tried `leg.get_children()` and it returns `matplotlib.offsetbox.VPacker` and `matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch` objects, none of which has the property `get_color()`. The solution link has a working example for lines, sorry with scatter plots I only has a non-working example...

Comment: a non-working example is fine. Please, just make a simple example that shows how you create the scatter plots and the legend. If it doesn't work, please just say what errors you get.

Comment: As of matplotlib version 3.3.0, you can now directly use the keyword argument `labelcolor` as described in this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63273370/6135182](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63273370/6135182)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems complicated but does give you what you want. Suggestions are welcomed. I use `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to get the markers and use `tuple(handle.get_facecolor()[0])` to get the matplotlib color tuple. Made an example with a really simple scatter plot like this:

## Edit:

As **ImportanceOfBeingErnest** pointed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490815/matplotlib-match-legend-text-color-with-symbol-in-scatter-plot/44491510#44495639):

1. `leg.legendHandles` will return the legend handles;
2. List, instead of tuple, can be used to assign matplotlib color.

Codes are simplified as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue']:
    x, y = rand(2, 10)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=color, label=color)

leg = ax.legend()
for handle, text in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.get_texts()):
    text.set_color(handle.get_facecolor()[0])

plt.show()
```

What I got is:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Scatter plots have a facecolor and an edgecolor. The legend handler for a scatter is a `PathCollection`.

So you can loop over the legend handles and set the text color to the facecolor of the legend handle

```
for h, t in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.get_texts()):
    t.set_color(h.get_facecolor()[0])
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(3):
    x,y = np.random.rand(2, 20)
    ax.scatter(x, y, label="Label {}".format(i))

leg = ax.legend()

for h, t in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.get_texts()):
    t.set_color(h.get_facecolor()[0])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `legendHandles`! Somehow I didn't find it in the doc, although it seems to give the same results as `get_legend_handles_labels()`

Comment: Thank you for showing `leg.legendHandles` and color as a `list`. Learned a lot!

Comment: `legend.legendHandles` is the list of handles that are actually in the legend, while `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` returns the list of handles and labels that would qualify for being in the legend. So the difference would be visible when not including all artists in the legend or when putting artists in the legend, which are not part of the plot.

Comment: I tried with the code, and If I use `ax.plot` instead of `ax.scatter`, then I have to change it to `h.get_color()`. Is there a more generic way to do this?

Comment: @steven the `ax.plot` case is what the question starts with and then looks for an alternative for the `scatter` case.