# Legend Text Color in Matplotlib with Errorbar Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the text in my legend to match the color of the lines from the plot. There is a nice summary of how to do this by Dan, over here: [Matplotlib: Color-coded text in legend instead of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828246/matplotlib-color-coded-text-in-legend-instead-of-a-line/18476999#18476999)

However, it does not seem to work for errorbar plot types. Does anyone have an idea of what handle I should use to make this change?

Here's some example code that shows how it works with the plot type element, but doesn't work with the errorbar type element:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.1,4,0.5)
y1 = np.exp(-x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)*1.2+0.25

plot = plt.figure()
ax = plot.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

ax.plot(x,y1,color="red",label="Y1")
ax.errorbar(x,y2,yerr=0.1,color="blue",marker='*',capsize=4,label="Y2")

leg = ax.legend();

for line, text in zip(leg.get_lines(), leg.get_texts()):
       text.set_color(line.get_color())
```

And here's an example of how that plot looks:

[Code will change text color of plot types but not errorbar types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEvNG.png)

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.get_lines()` method gives you the lines in the legend.

```
[h for h in self.legendHandles if isinstance(h, Line2D)]
```

The errorbar is not a `Line2D`. So in principle you could instead iterate over `leg.legendHandles`. The problem is then that colors are not well specified. They may be names or arrays. This needs to be taken care of such that the  solution becomes a bit more complicated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.1,4,0.5)
y1 = np.exp(-x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)*1.2+0.25

plot = plt.figure()
ax = plot.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

ax.plot(x,y1,color="red",label="Y1")
ax.errorbar(x,y2,yerr=0.1,color="blue",marker='*',capsize=4,label="Y2")

leg = ax.legend();

for artist, text in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.get_texts()):
    col = artist.get_color()
    if isinstance(col, np.ndarray):
        col = col[0]
    text.set_color(col)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I also provided an even more general solution to the linked question.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!